# What R object can hold variables so I can iterate over the object?

Tags: r, for-loop, variables

This seems simple, but I'm spinning my wheels.

I have 80 character variables. I want to 1) view the unique values in each variable, 2) view the number of unique values, and 3) convert some or all variables to factors.

I can do this one-by-one by explicitly naming the columns:

```
df$var1 # "val2" "val2" "val1" "val2" ... 
unique(df$var1) # "val1" "val2" "val3" 
length(unique(df$var1)) # 3 
df$var1 = as.factor(df$var1)
```

... although this produces an error:

```
levels(df@var1)
# Error in levels(df@var1) : 
# trying to get slot "var1" from an object (class "tbl_df") 
# that is not an S4 object
```

But when I create a list of the character variables and try the same as above it doesn't work.

```
# create list of char vars
char_vars_names <- names(df[, sapply(df, class) == 'character'])
char_vars_names
#[1] "var1" "var2" "var3" ...

df$char_vars_names[1]  # NULL
# Warning message: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'char_vars_names'.

unique(df$char_vars_names[1])  # NULL
length(unique(df$char_vars_names[1]))  # 0
```

Once I get the above working I figure I can iterate over the list with a for loop:

```
for (i in range(length(char_vars_names))) {
    # code
```

}

What is it about the char_vars_names object or elsewhere in my code that makes this not work?

In case it's helpful, here's my imports and data ingestion prior to the above code:

```
library(car) 
library(lattice)
library(tidyverse)
library(ISLR)
library(Lahman) 
library(mdsr)

file = "file.csv"
df <- read_csv(
    file=file,
    col_names = TRUE,  
    skip = 3,
    na = c("", "NA"))
```

Comment: Try `df[[char_vars_names]][1]`. The `$` notation can't take advantage of variable substitution, but the double brackets can.

Comment: Also your use of `range` will not work (I'm guessing you're coming from Python). `for (i in char_vars_names)` might be what you're after.

Comment: I get an error when I use the double bracket below,  but maybe I didn't follow your suggestion correctly:

`char_vars_names  # [1] "var1" "var2" ...`
`char_vars_names[1]  # "var1"`

# Works/works/doesn't work:
`df$var1  # "val2" "val2" "val1" ...`
`df[char_vars_names][1]    # "val2" "val2" "val1" ...`
`df[[char_vars_names]][1]  # Error in .subset2(x, i) : recursive indexing failed at level 2`

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the for loop. That is exactly what I'll need as soon as I can get the rest of the code to work!